# How to filter an array based on odd or even index value

Tags: php, arrays

How can I filter out the array entries with an odd or even index number?

```
Array
(
    [0] => string1
    [1] => string2
    [2] => string3
    [3] => string4
)
```

I want it remove the [0] and [2] entries from the array.
Or say I have 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9; I would need to remove 0,2,4,6,8.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`foreach($arr as $key => $value) if($key&1) unset($arr[$key]);`

The above removes odd number positions from the array, to remove even number positions, use the following:

Instead `if($key&1)` you can use `if(!($key&1))`

Comment: This removes every odd number, like [1] and [3]. How can I remove every even number, like [0], [2]...?

Comment: just change the if statement in Thinker's code to (!$key&1) ... 
foreach($arr as $key => $value) if(!$key&1) unset($arr[$key]);

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it gives me [1],[2],[3], but not the [4], it should only give me [1] and [3]. Any thoughts?

Comment: If  !$key&1 not works it is because operator precedence. I edited my code.

Comment: what "&" is actually doing in if($key&1) ...And How it knows whether it is ODD or EVEN

Answer (score 2):

Here's a "hax" solution:

Use array_filter in combination with an "isodd" function.

array_filter seems only to work on values, so you can first array_flip and then use array_filter.

```
array_flip(array_filter(array_flip($data), create_function('$a','return $a%2;')))
```

Comment: create_function is not recommended as it has a memory leak.

Comment: And they're hard to read as well :) Anonymous functions would be worth looking at for when 5.3.0 is released (http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Awesome, anonymous functions! Didn't know that they were planned, thanks

Comment: Because `array_filter()` has evolved to enjoy `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` there is no need for this "hax" solution.  No one should be using this for any reason in modern PHP development.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use SPL FilterIterator like this:

```
class IndexFilter extends FilterIterator {
    public function __construct (array $data) {
        parent::__construct(new ArrayIterator($data));
    }   

    public function accept () {
        # return even keys only
        return !($this->key() % 2);
    }     
}

$arr      = array('string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4');
$filtered = array();

foreach (new IndexFilter($arr) as $key => $value) {
    $filtered[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function odd($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is odd
    return($var & 1);
}

function even($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is even
    return(!($var & 1));
}

$array1 = array("a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5);
$array2 = array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

echo "Odd :\n";
print_r(array_filter($array1, "odd"));
echo "Even:\n";
print_r(array_filter($array2, "even"));
?>

Odd :
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [c] => 3
    [e] => 5
)
Even:
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [2] => 8
    [4] => 10
    [6] => 12
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this...

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    if($i % 2) // OR if(!($i % 2))
    {
        unset($array[$i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that should be a < instead of a <=

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$array = array(0, 3, 5, 7, 20, 10, 99,21, 14, 23, 46); 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) 

{ 
        if ($array[$i]%2 !=0)
        echo $array[$i]."<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(0 => 'string1', 1 => 'string2', 2 => 'string3', 3 => 'string4');

// Removes elements of even-numbered keys
$test1 = array_filter($array, function($key) {
    return ($key & 1);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

// Removes elements of odd-numbered-keys
$test2 = array_filter($array, function($key) {
    return !($key & 1);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

This answer is a bit of an improvement over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/738191/2518200) answer. You can use anonymous functions instead of `create_function`. Also, `array_filter` takes an optional flag parameter that lets you specify that the callback function takes the key as its only argument. So you don't need to use `array_flip` to get an array of keys.