# What am I doing wrong by splitting my array on odd/even numeric keys?

Tags: php, arrays, split

I'm having trouble splitting an array in two.

```
Array
(
    [0] => livree
    [1] => 2011-12-26
    [2] => livree
    [3] => 2011-12-27
    [4] => livree
    [5] => 2011-12-28
    [6] => livree
    [7] => 2011-12-29
    [8] => livree
    [9] => 2011-12-30
    [10] => livree
    [11] => 2011-12-31
    [12] => livree
    [13] => 2012-01-01
    [14] => livree
    [15] => 2012-01-02
    [16] => livree
    [17] => 2012-01-03
    [18] => en_cours
    [19] => 2012-01-04
    [20] => en_cours
    [21] => 2012-01-05
    [22] => en_cours
    [23] => 2012-01-06
    [24] => en_cours
    [25] => 2012-01-07
    [26] => en_cours
    [27] => 2012-01-08
)
```

I use those functions to detect odd/even key and split it in two differents array:

```
function odd($var){return($var & 1);}
function even($var){return(!($var & 1));}


$odd = array_filter($vb, "odd");
$even = array_filter($vb, "even");
```

I'm only having thoses two array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2011-12-26
    [1] => 2011-12-27
    [2] => 2011-12-28
    [3] => 2011-12-29
    [4] => 2011-12-30
    [5] => 2011-12-31
    [6] => 2012-01-01
    [7] => livree
    [8] => livree
    [9] => en_cours
    [10] => en_cours
    [11] => en_cours
    [12] => en_cours
    [13] => en_cours
)



Array
(
    [0] => livree
    [1] => livree
    [2] => livree
    [3] => livree
    [4] => livree
    [5] => livree
    [6] => livree
    [7] => 2012-01-02
    [8] => 2012-01-03
    [9] => 2012-01-04
    [10] => 2012-01-05
    [11] => 2012-01-06
    [12] => 2012-01-07
    [13] => 2012-01-08
)
```

What did I do wrong??? Thx for your help!

Comment: [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) works on values, not keys. You need to try something else, see http://www.php.net/ref.array and http://www.php.net/array

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738168/filter-array-odd-even

Comment: Your example array and code do not produce the two arrays you have shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`array_filter` passes you the value, not the key. I fail to understand why you are getting exactly these results, but anyway, you don't need array_filter at all:

Faster way to do it:

```
$odd = $even = array();
for ($i = 0, $l = count($vb); $i < $l;) { // Notice how we increment $i each time we use it below, by two in total
    $even[] = $vb[$i++];
    $odd[] = $vb[$i++];
}
```

Cuter way to do it:

```
foreach (array_chunk($vb, 2) as $chunk) {
    $even[] = $chunk[0];
    $odd[] = $chunk[1];
}
```

...and for some reason I also think you really wanted an associative array:

```
foreach (array_chunk($vb, 2) as $chunk) {
    $days[$chunk[1]] = $chunk[0];
}
```

Comment: You, my friend, rock! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($yourarray); $i = $i+2) {
    $even[] = $yourarray[$i];
    $odd[] = $yourarray[$i+1];
}
// See if the array is having even no. of elements for example if it would be having 28 elements instead of 27 then we will miss the 28th element in the loop. So we have to check that and add it to the even array.

if((sizeof($yourarray) % 2) == 0)
    $even[] = $yourarray[sizeof($yourarray-1)];
```

Thats it!

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_odd($num)
 {

    if ($num % 2 == 0)
        return false;
     else     
        return true;
}

$even_array=array();
$odd_rray=array(); 

foreach($array as $key=>$val)
{
    if(is_odd($key))
        array_push($odd_array,$val)
    else
        array_push($even_array,$val)
}

print_r($even_array);
print_r($odd_array);
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not good with PHP, but here's what I would do in C# (and without using LINQ):

```
object[] input = new object{
   "livee", new DateTime(2012,1,1),
   "livee", new DateTime(2012,1,2),
   "livee", new DateTime(2012,1,3),
   "livee", new DateTime(2012,1,4)};

ArrayList stringValues = new ArrayList();
ArrayList dateValues = new ArrayList();

for(int i = 0; i< input.Length; i ++)
{
  if(i % 2 == 0)
    stringValues.Add(input[i]);
  else
    dateValues.Add(input[i]);
}
```

Using LINQ in C# the following is possible:

```
string[] stringValues = input.OfType<string>().ToArray();
DateTime[] dateValues = input.OfType<DateTime>().ToArray();
```

Alternatively, we can also do:

```
object[] stringValues = input.Where((obj, index) => index % 2 == 0).ToArray();
object[] dateValues = input.Where((obj, index) => index % 2 == 1).ToArray();
```

There are a few PHP implementations, for example at http://phplinq.codeplex.com/.

Comment: nice, thx for trying to help. I retain @sad_dude solution. Again, merci beaucoup! :)